# edit csv element within row

Tags: python, list, csv, row

I have a csv file:

```
users,grade
adam,100
jake,90
```

I want to be able to delete or add an element under the users row.
I also need to change an element in the grade row (specifically to each user)

i.e. adam's grade has changed so I want to be able to write something in python to change the grade under the name
`adam`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add Python code that you've tried so far. This smells like a homework question!

Comment: Read the csv using csv.DictReader. Organise into a list of dictionaries, where each row is a dictionary. - The question then becomes how to add keys to a dictionary OR change the value of a key in a dictionary.

Comment: I don't even know where to start... I mean, can I use rows in a python list? @Brian